# target only some of divs content

Tags: jquery

I have the below html markup

```
<div class="title-wrap">
      <span class="title">Hello World</span>
        <br/>
   This title is about Hello World
</div>
```

and I want to target the text 'This title is about Hello World'

But I can't work out how to do this with out also including the span? Is it possible to achieve this with the html in this format?

I have tried using

```
var test = (jQuery('.title-wrap').text() || '' );
alert (test);
```

but this returns

```
Hello World

This title is about Hello World
```

as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/Y6dcU/).

Comment: So what exactly you want to retrieve? The last line in the `text()` or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can use this:

```
var test = (jQuery('.title-wrap')
        .clone()    //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove()   //remove all the children
        .end()  //again go back to selected element
        .text() || '' );
alert (test);
```

#### Output:

```
This title is about Hello World
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6dcU/6/

Comment: But this will only work if what you want to select is the only non-child portion of the element.

Comment: @Hailwood Yeah, and that is what the OP needs... :) I just answered the requirement.

Comment: In this example yeah, but for future readers I thought it might be useful to make it clear ;)

Comment: @Hailwood I guess I have explained what should be done in the comments. Anyways, what do you suggest to make it better?

Comment: In terms of the answer, nothing :), not much you could do really and is exactly how I would have done it, this is more a structural problem of the OP's html :)

Comment: This works well thanks, unfortunately I can't control the html here as I would not have structured it like this. thanks.

Comment: Actually I lie, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery#4399718

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get all the child nodes of `.title-wrap` then use [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to select the last one since that's the one you want.

```
jQuery('.title-wrap').contents().last().text()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6dcU/11/

Answer (score -2):

Try wrapping it in a span element. You can use a header(h1, h2, etc) to substitute the first span, or you can use an id or class attribute to get a specific reference:

```
<div class="title-wrap">
    <span class="title">Hello World</span>
    <br>
    <span id="myTitle">This title is about Hello World<span>
</div>
```

In JS you would use:

```
var test = (jQuery('#myTitle').text() || '' );
alert (test);
```